# Pandas - Extract string using a specific pattern in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my Dataframe that has data in the below format:

```
id, value
10001, "[{'self': 'https://www.weburl.com', 'value': 'Value 1', 'id': '101'}, 
   {'self': 'https://www.weburl.com', 'value': 'Value 2', 'id': '102'}]"
10002, "[{'self': 'https://www.weburl.com', 'value': 'Value 1', 'id': '101'}, 
   {'self': 'https://www.weburl.com', 'value': 'Value 2', 'id': '102'}, 
   {'self': 'https://www.weburl.com', 'value': 'Value 4', 'id': '104'}]"
```

I am trying to extract data such that I get the below output (extract all values corresponding to value field) as a new column:

```
id, new_value
10001, Value 1, Value 2
10002, Value 1, Value 2, Value 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your values are valid `json`, you could use `ast.literal_eval` with list comprehension:

```
df["value"] = df["value"].apply(literal_eval)
df["value"] = [", ".join(k["value"] for k in i) for i in df["value"]]

print (df)

      id                      value
0  10001           Value 1, Value 2
1  10002  Value 1, Value 2, Value 4
```

Comment: thanks it worked well. Just trying to figure a way out to handle null in between...